# pinax error: no module named debug toolbar

Tags: python, django, pinax

I am developing a project with pinax and django 1.3.1 have successfully installed the virtualenv,pinax and other requirements and activated it created a project using `pinax-admin.py setup_project mysite`.

The project is created successfully but each time i run`manage.py syncdb`, the command line returns an error `no module named debug-toolbar`.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 21):

You need to install [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

Comment: i did what u told me to  but now it returns a new error 'no module named compressor`

Comment: Well that's a different problem. You should install the django_compressor package too. 
In short, you should meet all of its dependencies before you can use it.